# Pitchers winning consecutive Cy Young awards

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb, awards

How many pitchers have won back-to-back Cy Young awards?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cy_Young_Award#Multiple_winners) there have been 18 multiple Cy Young award winners.

9 of them won in consecutive years.

- Roger Clemens (1986-1987, 1997-1998)
- Randy Johnson (1999-2002)
- Greg Maddux (1992-1995)
- Sandy Koufax (1965-1966)
- Pedro Martinez (1999-2000)
- Jim Palmer (1975-1976)
- Clayton Kershaw (2013-2014)
- Tim Lincecum (2008-2009)
- Denny McLain (1968-1969)